# Composite functions of domain natural numbers dealing with perfect squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The domain of a function f is the set of natural numbers. The function is defined as follows:
$$f(n) =n+[\sqrt{n}] $$

Where $[x] $=nearest integer smaller than or equal to x. For example, $[$pi$]$ =3.

Prove that for every natural number m the following sequence contains at
least one perfect square
$$m, f(m), f^2 (m), f^3 (m)........ $$

The notation $f^k$ denotes the function obtained by composing f with itself k times, e.g.,$f^2 = f ◦ f$.

My attempt:
I don't know what to say but I have just used numbers to put in the equation to verify. Other than this I am not  able to think anything about it.

Comment: consider what happens when n = 101.  Then consider what happens when n = 102, n=103, ..., n=110.  Then formulate a hypothesis (i.e. preliminary lemma) and prove it.  Then use the lemma to prove the initial assertion.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to which numbers you used "to put in the equation to verify" and how you did that? Did you use a computer program? Which range of numbers did you test (a computer could test a very large range)?

Comment: No did not use computer program. Just randomly put 1,2,3 or 10..

Comment: @user2661923 I don't know about lemma. Can you provide me any other information  on this *lemma*?

Comment: @user2661923 can you provide any information about lemmas?

Comment: @jayant98 *lemma* simply refers to *any* **intermediate** result that helps you prove the initial assertion.  Examining $m, f(m), f^2(m), ...$ when $m = 101: m = 10^2 + 1,$ while $f^2(m) = 11^2.$  Similarly, when $m = 102, m = 10^2 + 2,$ while $f^2(m) = 11^2 + 1,$ and $f^4(m) = 12^2.$  Per my original comment, similarly explore each $m \in \{103, ..., 110\}.$  Look for a **pattern.**  Then ask yourself what hypothesis (i.e. *lemma*) does the pattern suggest that would serve as a preliminary result that would help you prove the initial assertion.  Then prove this preliminary result.

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$n = m^2+k$
where
$1 \le k \le 2m$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(n) 
&=n+[\sqrt{n}]\\
&=m^2+k+[\sqrt{m^2+k}]\\
&=m^2+k+m\\
\end{array}
$

If $1 \le k \le m$ then

$\begin{array}\\
f^{(2)}(n)=f(f(n)) 
&=m^2+k+m+[\sqrt{m^2+k+m}]\\
&=m^2+k+m+m\\
&=m^2+2m+k\\
&=(m+1)^2+k-1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$f(f(n))$
is one closer to a square than
$f(n)$.
In particular,
if $k=1$ then
$f(f(n))$ is a square.

If $m+1 \le k \le 2m$ then

$\begin{array}\\
f^{(2)}(n)=f(f(n)) 
&=m^2+k+m+[\sqrt{m^2+k+m}]\\
&=m^2+2m+1+k-(m+1)+[\sqrt{m^2+2m+1+k-(m+1)}]\\
&=(m+1)^2+k-(m+1)+(m+1)\\
&=(m+1)^2+k\\
\end{array}
$

and
$k-(m+1)
=(k-m)-1
\lt k-m$
so the difference between $k$
and the square below it
decreases by $1$.
Repeating this $m$ times
brings it down where
$k \le m$
(where "$m$" is the current
square, not the original one)
and the paragraph above applies.

In both cases,
eventually
$f^{(j)}(n)
=\lfloor \sqrt{f^{(j)}(n)} \rfloor ^2
$.